# Parsing error: Invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить проблему с линтером. Есть ошибка при запуске кода.

> error  Parsing error: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=tag=")\w{1,}/:
> Invalid group

Сам код работает, почему тогда ошибка?

```js
 function transformStringToHtml(element) {
    const regTag = /(?<=tag\=")\w{1,}/g;
    return `<${element.match(regTag)}></${element.match(regTag)}>`;
}

console.log(transformStringToHtml('tag="div"'));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В браузере все работает, проблема только в линтере, ошибка Parsing error: Invalid regular expression Invalid group. Вот я и думаю что не так с группами, код же работает как нужно

Comment: Возможно нужно отдельно прописать пожжержку [lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind)